# Elastic-search Nested query building

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I'm pretty new to elastic search and would like to write a query for all of the values a specific field? I mean, say i have a field "Number" and "change_manager_group"... I have tried the below query to print all the Numbers in the Index for past 12 hours which when matches "change_manager_group"

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/index_test/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
> {
>     "query": {
>       "bool": {
>         "must": [
>           {
>             "match_all": {}
>           },
>           {
>             "exists": {
>               "field": "Number"
>             }
>           },
>           {
>             "match_phrase": {
>               "change_manager_group": {
>                 "query": "Change Managers - 2"
>                }
>             }
>           },
>           {
>             "range": {
>               "actual_start": {
>                 "gte": 1555952852234,
>                 "lte": 1556039252234,
>                 "format": "epoch_millis"
>               }
>             }
>           }
>         ],
>         
>       }
>    }
> }
> '
```

Unluckily when I run the above query I get the below error :

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "json_parse_exception",
        "reason" : "Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@5c8e3895; line: 32, column: 8]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "json_parse_exception",
    "reason" : "Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@5c8e3895; line: 32, column: 8]"
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra comma after `must` array, remove that to make it a valid query

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/index_test/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
 {
     "query": {
       "bool": {
         "must": [
           {
             "match_all": {}
           },
           {
             "exists": {
               "field": "Number"
             }
           },
           {
             "match_phrase": {
               "change_manager_group": {
                 "query": "Change Managers - 2"
                }
             }
           },
           {
             "range": {
               "actual_start": {
                 "gte": 1555952852234,
                 "lte": 1556039252234,
                 "format": "epoch_millis"
               }
             }
           }
         ]                 <---- removed comma here

       }
    }
 }
```